# Mobile SDK - whitelist URLs cordova 2.3.0

Tags: javascript, mobile, mobilesdk, file-storage, cordova

I need to download some files with cordova with the mobile SDK. Apparently I need to allow the remote origin to download the file because I keep on getting http status 401 when I use the FileTrasnfer.

I tried to add to the project the folder res>xml and inside of it config.xml but when I launch the app I get "error initializing cordova: class not found"

Do you know if it's possible to download files with the cordova 2.3.0 distributed by sfdc? In android I need to extend the whitelist but I apparently I can't use the config.xml because it's not recognized.

Thanks for the assistance

T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code was correct, it was a problem with my configuration of the framework:

the app project has a project as library dependence (SmartStore). The SmartStore project had the res/xml/config.xml ! I just needed to add there the

```
<access origin="http://*.somedomain.com"></access>
```

not in the app project itself but in the library SmartStore! This is possible if you download the Mobile SDK library from git.